# Add external resources folder to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'd like to add a resource folder relative to the location of the jar (in addition to packaged resources within my jar), for example:

```
/Directory
    Application.jar
    /resources
        test.txt
```

I've tried the following:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/", "file:/resources/");
}
```

I've also tried:

```
.addResourceLocations("/resources/", "file:resources/");
```

Accessing `http://localhost:8080/resources/test.txt` with either setup leads to a whitelabel error page. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your second approach would work:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/", "file:resources/");
}
```

but *only* if you launched Spring Boot from `/Directory`, because `file:resources/` is a relative path.

```
cd Directory
java -jar Application.jar
```

It's nice if you can pack everything into the jar, but if you have to reference external resources, you should use [absolute paths](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#resources-filesystemresource-caveats) to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/files/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/location1/", "file:/location2/");
}
```

access file using http://localhost:{port}/files/image.png