# spring Resource handler not handling /../**

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot with thymeleaf and all my resources are outside spring application on a path like `"/../../css/main.css"`. On dev env should resolve the path using an url and live env go on the path.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    String templates=env.getProperty("spring.thymeleaf.prefix");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/../../css/**")
            .addResourceLocations(templates);
}
// spring.thymeleaf.prefix = http://website.com/assets/
```

Why the resource handler is not handling these kind of resources, but if I `"/**"`  is handling without problems? Am I missing something?

Edit: if `resourceHandler` is `"/css/**"` and location is an url is not being handled either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference to external resources as you want cause resolver looking for resources from `classpath`.

Try to do it like in this issue - [Add external resources folder to Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339172/add-external-resources-folder-to-spring-boot) or in this - [How do I use Spring Boot to serve static content located in Dropbox folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123437/how-do-i-use-spring-boot-to-serve-static-content-located-in-dropbox-folder)

Comment: thank you. This indeed works for the live server, but for dev and testing I kind of gave up on this idea since I don't have access to resources locally and the only way to access them are through http. I'm trying to solve it with `ResourceResolver` by modifying the path with an url. Unfortunately is prepanding the path from matched resource handler (`/../../css/http://website.com/assets/`) and I don't see a way to remove it from `ResourceResolver`. I keep looking what I have to override for that

Comment: So if your resources placed in the external resource, why you didn't created something like `CDN` for this resources? Create separate project with static resources and reference on it.

Comment: unfortunately I have no access to that server to do what I want

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that using .. in the addResourceHandler is not valid but I do not have specific documentation to back it up.  The path is describing a pattern that the server gets not what is listed in the browser.  From the function doc: "based on the specified URL path patterns". If you reference .. from a browser that will still be changed to some absolute path to be sent to the server.  This is why your other versions work without issue.

Comment: when I write `<link th:href="@{/../../css/main.css}" />` that's also a path on the server, but not a visible path by spring-boot or thymeleaf. So, to understand, because is not a visible path is not being handled?

Comment: That path is being resolved on the browser so the server never sees the .. references so it can't be used in a path matching pattern.